# Puppeteer page.$eval throws an error if element with selector wasn't found

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm doing a webscraper which goes in several pages. I want to know if it's possible to ignore an error thrown when my selector doesn't exist in my current page. Most of the time, `.lot-page__lot__sold` exist, but sometimes not and that throw me an error

The error says:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: failed to find element
> matching selector ".lot-page__lot__sold"

```
 const rawSoldPrice = await page
    .$eval(".lot-page__lot__sold", (text) => text.textContent)
    .catch((err) => true);
```

What should I change in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `page.evaluate` instead, as `page.$eval` absolutely needs the element to exist.

```js
const elementTextContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const element = document.querySelector('.lot-page__lot__sold')
  if (element) {
    return element.textContent
  }

  return '';
})
```